# Primefaces menuitem deosn't work 2nd time it's clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've got code that renders a table of Media files. After following a Primefaces commandLink, the user can then click on a Primefaces menuitem and go to the table of Media files again.

Here's the line for the menuitem:

```
<p:menuitem value="My Media" url="/pages/media/myMedia.xhtml"/>
```

This is what's in myMedia.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition template="/template/menu_layout.xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:media="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/media">

    <ui:define name="title">
        My Media
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:panel styleClass="remove-rounded-corners">
            <media:mediaTable id="table" formId="myMediaTable"
                mediaList="#{myMedia}"
                fromPage="myMedia"
                updateId=":table:myMediaTable"
                mediaPage="#{myMediaUtil}" 
                tableVar="widgetMedia"/>
        </p:panel>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

The second time around the code issues a PropertyNotFoundException.  But, it's the same code that ran the first time without any errors.

Here's the error:

10:13:38,942 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-20) UT005023: Exception handling request to /TranscriptTool/pages/media/myMedia.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/media/mediaTable.xhtml @23,169 rendered="#{cc.attrs.mediaList.searchUtil.noRecordsFound}": The class 'tt.media.Video' does not have the property 'searchUtil'.
    at tt.jsf.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:63)
    at tt.jsf.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:77)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /resources/media/mediaTable.xhtml @23,169 rendered="#{cc.attrs.mediaList.searchUtil.noRecordsFound}": The class 'tt.media.Video' does not have the property 'searchUtil'.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:458)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1850)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CompositeRenderer.encodeChildren(CompositeRenderer.java:78)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:202)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeMarkup(PanelRenderer.java:119)
    at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at tt.jsf.FacesExceptionFilter.doFilter(FacesExceptionFilter.java:57)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'tt.media.Video' does not have the property 'searchUtil'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:568)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:229)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:139)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ContextualCompositeValueExpression.getValue(ContextualCompositeValueExpression.java:158)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 76 more

Here's line 23 from the mediaTable.xhtml file:

```
<p:panel rendered="#{cc.attrs.mediaList.searchUtil.noRecordsFound}" style="margin: 0 auto; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px; text-align: center;"> 
    <h:outputText value="No Records found"/>
</p:panel>
```

Any idea how to determine why it doesn't work after the first time?

This is code that worked on Glassfish but now we're trying to get it working on Wildfly 10.

Thanks,
Avis

Comment: _"Any idea how to determine why it doesn't work after the first time?"_ debugging requests and responses. Finding errors in your page/code, and doing as stated in "1." in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: please provide some code to see if there is something wrong

Comment: @YagamiLight: please don't ask for 'some code', always ask for a [mcve].

Comment: Fix ended up being duplicate variable names being used.